# is there any function like php explode in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a string `path1/path2`

I need to get the values of `path1` and `path2`.

how can i do it?

---

And what about getting the same from such string `http://www.somesite.com/#path1/path2`?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The plain JavaScript String object has a `split` method.

```
'path1/path2'.split('/')

'http://www.somesite.com/#path1/path2'.split('#').pop().split('/')

-> ['path1', 'path2']
```

However, for the second case, it's generally not a good idea to do your own URL parsing via string or regex hacking. URLs are more complicated than you think. If you have a `location` object or an `<a>` element, you can reliably pick the parts of the URL out of it using the `protocol`, `host`, `port`, `pathname`, `search` and `hash` properties.

Answer (score 2):

```
var path1 = "path1/path2".split('/')[0];
var path2 = "path1/path2".split('/')[1];
```

for the 2nd one, if you are getting it from your url you can do this.

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
var path1 = hash.split('#')[1].split('/')[0];
var path2 = hash.split('#')[1].split('/')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = 'http://www.somesite.com/#path1/path2';
var arr = /#(.*)/g.exec(url);

alert(arr[1].split('/'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use jQuery for this, Javascripts plain old [Split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method should help you out.

Also, for your second string if you're dealing with URL's you can have a look at the [Location](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp) object as this gives you access to the port, host etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript `'path1/path2'.split('/')` for example. Gives you back an array where 0 is path1 and 1 is path2.

There is no need to use jquery